# PostgreSQL convert column from inet to text

Tags: postgresql, types, inet

I'd like to change type of column from **inet** to **text**. So, I execute:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN col TYPE text;
```

But then I found out that for all values was added mask.
For example: 
`192.168.100.141 -> 192.168.100.141/32`.
Is it possible to change **inet** column to **text** without any changes in this column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [host()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-net.html) to extract just the ip address:

```
ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN col TYPE text USING host(col);
```