# Java InetAddress to PostgreSQL inet and vice versa

Tags: java, postgresql, ip

I'd like to use the PSQL inet datatype, but it doesn't accept strings (getRemoteAddr()) or byte[] (InetAddress).

Is there a way to convert it properly using Java?

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29101458/postgresql-convert-column-from-inet-to-text

Comment: Maybe, but that's converting the inet datatype to something else. I'd like to keep using inet and convert it properly to a datatype Java can handle and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. I was able to read Inet Postgres Type using InetAddress but faced error when inserting the same InetAddress type to postgres that had inet type.

**Solved it by defining custom hibernate type**

***PgInet->***

```
    public class PgInet implements Serializable {

    private InetAddress address;

    public PgInet() {}

    public PgInet(InetAddress address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public InetAddress getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof PgInet)) {
            return false;
        }
        PgInet other = (PgInet) obj;
        if (address == null) {
            if (other.address != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!address.equals(other.address)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("PgInet [address=");
        builder.append(address);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

***PGInetType ->***

```
    public class PgInetType implements UserType {

    public PgInetType() {}

    @Override
    public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) {
        return deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return new PgInet(((PgInet) value).getAddress());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(Object value) {
        return (value != null) ? (Serializable) deepCopy(value) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) {
        return x == y || ( x != null && y != null && x.equals( y ) );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(Object x) {
        return (x != null) ? x.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names,
                              SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object owner) throws SQLException {
        PgInet address = null;

        String ipStr = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (ipStr != null) {
            try {
                address = new PgInet(InetAddress.getByName(ipStr));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                throw new HibernateException(e);
            }
        }

        return address;
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
                            SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        }
        else {
            PGobject pgObj = new PGobject();
            pgObj.setType("inet");
            pgObj.setValue(((PgInet) value).getAddress().getHostAddress());
            st.setObject(index, pgObj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner) {
        return deepCopy(original);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public Class returnedClass() {
        return PgInet.class;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] {Types.OTHER};
    }

}
```

***Usage->***

```
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name="pgInet", typeClass=PgInetType.class)

})
public class Test{
    @Column(name = "ip")
    @Type(type="pgInet")
    private PgInet ip;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same question as [How to get inet in entity class in spring using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42038341).

---

After few days research, I find out no need to reinvent the wheel in 2022.

There is a lib [vladmihalcea/hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) implement `Inet column type` & `Inet Hibernate Type`.

#### resource

mvn repos: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.vladmihalcea

tutorial: https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-inet-type-hibernate/

GitHub: https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types

#### Example from [tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/postgresql-inet-type-hibernate/)

```
@Entity(name = "Event")
@Table(name = "event")
@TypeDef(
    name = "ipv4",
    typeClass = PostgreSQLInetType.class,
    defaultForType = Inet.class
)

public class Event {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @Column(
        name = "ip",
        columnDefinition = "inet"
    )
    private Inet ip;
 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
 
    public Inet getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
 
    public void setIp(String address) {
        this.ip = new Inet(address);
    }
}
```

Work as expected in `spring-boot 2.7.1`, `hibernate 5.6.9`.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply call InetAddress.getByName(String host) passing in your textual IP address.**

From the JavaDoc: The host name can either be a machine name, such as "java.sun.com", or a textual representation of its IP address.

~ InetAddress javadoc

**If you were asking about getting the string from the IP:**

String getHostAddress()
*Returns the IP address string in textual presentation.*

String getHostName()
*Gets the host name for this IP address.*

**Sorry I couldn't be of more help.**